# Retrieve XML from HTTP POST Request Payload

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-xml

I have an ActiveX that POSTs to the server (HTTP Handler) with a payload of a certain XML document.

Is there a better way to retrieve the payload into XML than the below?

```
private static byte[] RequestPayload()
{
   int bytesToRead = HttpContext.Current.Request.TotalBytes;
   return (HttpContext.Current.Request.BinaryRead(bytesToRead));
}

using (var mem = new MemoryStream(RequestPayload()))
{
    var docu = XDocument.Load(mem);
}
```

Once I have the "docu" I can query using LINQ to XML.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply load the XML from the InputStream of the Request e.g.

```
XDocument doc;
using (Stream input = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)
{
  doc = XDocument.Load(input);
}
```

there is no need for a MemoryStream in my view.

Comment: Thanks! I"n my case had to have a byte[] not a Stream.

Comment: Just in case you are not using the 4.0 framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666835/xdocument-load-error