# XDocument.Load() Error

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have some code:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = 
    new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = new System.Xml.Linq.XDocument();
    doc.Load(new System.IO.StringReader(sr.ReadToEnd()));
}
```

I can't load my response in my XML document. I get the following error:

```
Member 'System.XMl.Linq.XDocument.Load(System.IO.TextReader' cannot be accessed 
with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.
```

This is becoming really frustrating.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unlike [`XmlDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load.aspx), [`XDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx) is a static method *returning* a new `XDocument`:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(sr.ReadToEnd()));
```

It seems pretty pointless to read the stream to the end *then* create a `StringReader` though. It's also pointless creating the `StreamReader` in the first place - and if the XML document *isn't* in UTF-8, it could cause problems. Better:

For .NET 4, where there's an `XDocument.Load(Stream)` overload:

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
    }
}
```

For .NET 3.5, where there isn't:

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(stream));
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, just let LINQ to XML do *all* the work:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
```

EDIT: Note that the compiler error did give you enough information to get you going: it told you that you can't call `XDocument.Load` as `doc.Load`, and to give the type name instead. Your next step should have been to consult the documentation, which of course gives examples.

Comment: I get the error `cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'System.Xml.XmlReader' when do the solution you recommend.

Comment: I was using JesseLiberty's example and that is where I in trouble.

Comment: @JoeTyman: Where does `XmlReader` come into it? I haven't specified anything that requires an `XmlReader`. Which of my code samples did that error come from, and where?

Comment: @JoeTyman: Ah - `XDocument.Load(Stream)` was only introduced in .NET 3.5. Editing...

Comment: I know this is old, but I have to say thank you...  I've been chasing my tail for most of the day today trying to figure out why this isn't working, and I've been over every inch of the method declaration on MSDN and it wasn't very clear that this was a function that returned the value...